# Hibernate DAO cannot save foreign key using drop down list with spring boot and thymeleaf and i dont want to use jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, thymeleaf

this is my html code my code always save null in foreign key columns
please help and try to correct my code please

```
<div th:if="${mode == 'MODE_NEW'}">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form autocomplete="off"
                  th:action="@{/admin/user-task/save}" 
                  th:object="${user_task}" method="post" class="form-horizontal"
                  role="form">
                <fieldset>
                    <!-- Form Name -->
                    <legend>User Task Assignment</legend>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" th:field="${user_task.id}" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"
                                    title="Select User" name="user" tabindex="-98">

                                <option th:each="user: ${users}" th:value="${user.id}"
                                        th:text="${user.name}"></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Task</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"
                                    title="Select Task" name="task" tabindex="-98">
                                <option th:each="task: ${tasks}" th:value="${task.id}"
                                        th:text="${task.name}"></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Button (Double) -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submitButton"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton"
                                    class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse"
                                    onclick="window.history.back()">Cancel</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my controller where i have tried every thing but it not save directly  please suggest in my code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveUserTask(@Valid UserTask userTask,BindingResult bindingResult) throws UserTaskException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/user-task/all");
    modelAndView.addObject("auth", getUser());
    modelAndView.addObject("control", getUser().getRole().getRole());
    User user=new User();
    user.getUserTask();
    Task task =new Task();
    task.getUserTask();
    userTask.setTask(task);
    userTask.setUser(user);
    userTaskService.save(userTask);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

this is my dao interface in which calls method

```
public interface UserTaskDao {

    public void save(UserTask user_task) throws UserTaskException;

}
```

this my DaoImpl in which I use hibernate session

```
@Override
public void save(UserTask user_task) throws UserTaskException {

    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {

    session.save(user_task);
    }catch(HibernateException e) {
        throw new UserTaskException("Error while saving user Task id and role id: "+e);
    }
}
```

this is my service class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserTaskService {

    @Autowired
    private final UserTaskDao userTaskDao; //userTaskDao

    public UserTaskService(UserTaskDao userTaskDao) {
        this.userTaskDao = userTaskDao;
    }               

    public void save(UserTask user_task) throws UserTaskException{
        userTaskDao.save(user_task);
    }       
}
```

My UserTask.java Class

```
@Entity(name="user_task")
public class UserTask implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TASK_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Task task;


    public UserTask(UserTaskBean userTaskBean) {

    }

    public UserTask() {


    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


    public Task getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(Task task) {
        this.task = task;
    }



}
```

In my User.java class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<UserTask> userTask = new HashSet<UserTask>();
```

In my Task.java class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
private Set<UserTask> userTask = new HashSet<UserTask>();
```

Comment: Where are you populating the `user` and `task` fields of  the `UserTask` object with the values you want to have set as foreign keys?

Comment: I have given this UserTask class please see my UserTask class

Comment: Yeah, but where are you calling the methods to set `user` and `task`?

Comment: I edit in my question i call set methods in controller but it was not worked for me

Comment: after set methods it gives exception   (org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.sms.enterprise.model.Task
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:347) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final])

Comment: Please look up "cascades" or save those objects first to the database, this is Hibernate 101

Comment: the ids are already saved int the database i want to get the id from database and save it to other table

Comment: That's not how Hibernate works, Hibernate thinks in objects. So, load the objects according to their IDs, set the managed entity on the user task and save the user task. Hibernate 101, as I said before.

Comment: can u show in my code please

Comment: if i Edit this code in DAOIMPL  (User uid=session.get(User.class, user.getId());
  uid.setId(uid.getId());
  user_task.setUser(uid);
  session.save(user_task);) it gives me null pointer exception